# document.ActiveElement always returns body Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, onfocus

So what was happening is like the title says. On **(focusout)** when I called a method that checks if an element is an **document.activeElement** (focused), I was always getting the **body** as a result. Only if I click on another window/inspector tools I was getting a correct result when doing a *console.log* which was in my case a button element.

Note that this is in Angular.

**Solution is below.**

component.html:

```
<button 
  (focusout)="_onFocusOut()" 
  class="typography-button" (keydown)="_onItemKeyDown($event)" 
  (click)="_selectItem(item)" #menuitem>
  {{ item.label }}
</button>
```

component.ts

```
_onFocusOut(): void{
  const isActiveElement = this.menuItemElements?.toArray().some(item => {
  // document.activeElement is always body
    return item.nativeElement == document.activeElement;
  });

  if(!isActiveElement){
    // do something
  }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

The solution was just to wrap the whole method logic in a **settimeout** method:

```
_onFocusOut(): void{
// add setTimeout with no value as a second parameter
    setTimeout(() => {
      const isActiveElement = this.menuItemElements?.toArray().some(item => {
        return item.nativeElement == document.activeElement;
      });

      if(!isActiveElement){
        this._toggled = false;
      }
    });
  }
```